# Popover text orientation not updating after rotation in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, popover

I am developing an iPhone app that presents a popover. When I rotate my phone, the popover's text correctly rotates along with the popover in case of iOS7. When I try to do the same in iOS8, the popover rotates but the text within does not. The text display is still aligned to the previous orientation.

How can I ensure my popover's text is properly aligned with the popover after a rotation?

Comment: You need to be more clear when asking a question, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask